# How to rewrite simple .js page view counter cookie function in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

Am trying to rewrite a simple (in theory) cookie-based page counter for a paywall using Rails's built in cookies features. Visit new page = increase cookie 'count' value by one, etc. When visitor gets to X page views, show paywall. This in a paywall.js file that uses jquery.cookie.js works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// create cookie
  var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // visited = 0
  var pageTitle = document.title;
  if (visited == 7) {
    $("p.counter").html("From this point, you will always see fancybox on next visit!");
    // open fancybox after 1 secs on 8th visit
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: "#inline"
        });
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    visited++; // increase counter of visits
    $("p.counter span").append(visited);
    // set new cookie value to match visits
    $.cookie('visited', visited, {
        expires: 365, // expires after one year
        path: "/"
    });
    return false;
}
}); // ready
```

The following, placed in the application controller, nearly works but the page counter is working using session[:counter]. The page count increases perfectly but it resets to zero and starts counting again if you close and reopen the browser (obviously):

```
before_filter :set_visitor_cookie

def set_visitor_cookie
  cookies[:visits] = {
    value: increment_counter,
    expires: 1.year.from_now
    }
end

def increment_counter
  if session[:counter].nil?
    session[:counter] = 0
  end
  session[:counter] += 1
end
```

So how do I write the increment_counter method, or the set_visitor_cookie method directly, to just increase the value by 1 on every page view?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, have done it. Not sure if I understand why the increment code works exactly as it does (if there are any Ruby experts around, jump in), but these three methods and the before filter work and do the same as the jquery code in the question, incrementing the counter in a cookie and not using sessions, so it persists across browser restarts (until someone clears their cookies, but we can worry about evercookie or fingerprinting another day). You could use this to call a paywall, another kind of popover or pretty much anything else I guess.

```
before_filter :set_visitor_cookie

def set_visitor_cookie
  cookies[:visits] = {
    value: increment_counter,
    expires: 1.year.from_now
    }

  paywall
end

def increment_counter
  @pageviews = cookies[:visits].to_i
  if @pageviews.nil?
    @pageviews == 0
  end
  @pageviews += 1
end

def paywall
  if cookies[:visits].to_i > 5
    flash[:success] = "Paywall time"
  end
end
```

Set the integer value in the paywall method to whatever you want for your paywall or popover, and change the code within the if clause to do whatever you want it do to when the counter goes beyond the count value.